# How to click html link with jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html link in which a modal window will be opened while clicking manually. Am using nyromodal, i want the modal window function to get triggered when the shortcut of ctrl+Q is pressed. the shortcut works well when we give just an alert. but not opening the modal.

I tried to trigger the modal function by defining the modal function in the shortcut. But no use. It will be fine if i can click the link dynamically using a jquery function. hopefully that might work. :( no ideas though. Any ideas and help thoughts are welcomed

```
shortcut.add("Ctrl+Q",function() {
$('.nyroModal').nyroModal();
});
```

The usual modal function is

```
$(function() {   $('.nyroModal').nyroModal(); });
```

It works fine when the link with class nyroModal is clicked but not with the shortcut

### html

```
<a href="new_creation.php" class="nyroModal">Componenets</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.nyroModal').nyroModal();

    shortcut.add("Ctrl+Q",function() {
        $('a.nyroModal').click();
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
shortcut.add("Ctrl+Q",function() {
   $('.nyroModal').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into this function which will handle shortcuts.

[Linkereeno](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2009/06/16/ctrl-key-combination-simple-jquery-plugin/)